Issue with Draggable Curve Segment and Y-Axis Alignment in PyQt5 PlotWidget
I have been struggling with a problem for about a month. I have used ChatGPT-4o during this time, but it hasn't provided a satisfactory solution. The issue is as follows:
When a user clicks on a part of a curve, the segmented part should be draggable up and down, with the y-axis values updating accordingly as the mouse moves. However, the problem arises when I drag the segment curve: the axis does not match the curve. Specifically, while the y-axis moves with the curve, the values of the curve no longer align with the axis, and they change inconsistently.
Here is a part of my code. Note that "self.p1" or "self.ui.pw" is a PlotWidget object defined in a UI file. We added all curves and view boxes to this main object. The code is written in Python and uses PyQt5. I used three functions to define these parts:
ok_on_segments(self): This function adds all segments into the "nv" view box and then adds it to "self.ui.pw".
on_curve_selected(self, curve_name): When the user clicks on a segment, this function is triggered. For each selected curve, I create a view box, set the exact range, enable dragging by mouse, fix all other curves, and add the new view box to the "self.ui.pw" object.
Despite this setup, the y-axis values do not maintain alignment with the dragged curve segment.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
def ok_on_segments(self):
    #creat style for curves
    global colors, curve_to_vb_map, num_curves
    if self.split_btn_flag == 1:
        curve_name_dict = dict()
        curve_name_dict_temp = dict()
        self.p1.removeItem(self.curve_3)
        self.p2.removeItem(self.curve_1)
        colors[num_import % len(colors)]
        color = colors[0] 
        width = 2  
        pen = pg.mkPen(color, width=width)
        
        #set data on a split curves
        for ind in range(self.segments_window.listWidget_complete.count()):
            list_item = self.segments_window.listWidget_complete.item(ind)
            if ind!=0:
                if list_item.flags() & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable:
                    if list_item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
                        if ind+1<=self.segments_window.listWidget_complete.count():
                            #convert s to min
                            x = []
                            try:
                                for item in self.data_dict[ind-1][f"step_{ind}"]["time"]:
                                    x.append(item/60)
                            except:
                                pass
                            
                            y = [x/self.sampleMass  for x in self.data_dict[ind-1][f"step_{ind}["dsc"]]
                            z = self.data_dict[ind-1][f"step_{ind}"]["temp"]
                            custom_pen,cl = self.apply_custom_style_DDSC(pen)
                            self.custom_pen_list_dsc.append(cl)
                            curve_name_dict[f'curve_{self.counter_name}'] = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y,pen=custom_pen)
                            curve_name_dict[f'curve_{self.counter_name}'].setClickable(True)
                            num_import_ = 1
                            
                            curves_dict[num_curves] = {'curve_name':f'curve_{self.counter_name}' , 'curve_label':'DSC' }
                            num_curves = num_curves + 1
                            num_import_ =str(num_import)
                            self.textItem = pg.TextItem(text=f"{num_import_}.{ind}", color=color, anchor=(0, 0), border=pg.mkPen(color=color), fill=pg.mkBrush(None))
                            last_point = x[-1], y[-1]
                            self.textItem.setPos(last_point[0], last_point[1])
                            # Create a new view box and add items
                            self.p1.addItem(self.textItem)
                            self.counter_name += 1
     self.curve_name_dict = curve_name_dict
     nv = self.create_new_viewbox('dsc','l')
     for i in range(self.counter_name):
            try:
                nv.addItem(curve_name_dict[f'curve_{i}'])
                
            except:
                pass
      self.ui.pw.addItem(nv)
      nv.setZValue(1)
      self.curve_name_dict = curve_name_dict
      for curve_name, curve in self.curve_name_dict.items():
            curve.sigClicked.connect(partial(self.on_curve_selected, curve_name))

def on_curve_selected(self, curve_name):
    print(curve_name)
    for i in range(len(list(self.curve_name_dict.keys()))):
        if list(self.curve_name_dict.keys())[i]==curve_name:
            print(i)
            color_number = self.custom_pen_list_dsc[i]
            break
    y_min = 100
    y_max = 0
    for items in self.curve_name_dict.values():
        if np.min(items.yData)<y_min:
            y_min = np.min(items.yData)
        if np.max(items.yData)>y_max:
            y_max = np.max(items.yData)
    
    dict_=self.curve_name_dict
    new_vbox = self.create_new_viewbox('DSC','l',color_number)
    if curve_name != self.current_name:
        curve = dict_[curve_name]
        new_vbox.addItem(dict_[curve_name])
        new_vbox.setZValue(1)
        self.ui.pw.addItem(new_vbox)
        self.ui.pw.setMouseEnabled(False) 
        new_vbox.setRange(yRange=(y_min, y_max))
        for k in  dict_.keys():
            if k!=curve_name:
                fixed_curve = FixedPlotDataItem(dict_[k].xData,dict_[k].yData)
                self.ui.pw.addItem(fixed_curve)
                
    self.current_viewbox = new_vbox 
    self.current_name = curve_name

def create_new_viewbox(self, label,pos,color='black'):
    new_viewbox = YAxisOnlyViewBox()
    
    # new_viewbox.setMouseMode(new_viewbox.RectMode)
    if pos == "l":
        self.p1.scene().addItem(new_viewbox)
        self.p1.showAxis('left')
        self.p1.getAxis('left').linkToView(new_viewbox)
        new_viewbox.setXLink(self.p1)
        self.configure_axis(self.p1.getAxis('left'), label,color)


class YAxisOnlyViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.setMouseMode(self.RectMode)
        self.draggableItem = None
        self.dragOffset = None
        self.setMouseEnabled(x=False,y=True)

class FixedPlotDataItem(pg.PlotDataItem):
    def mouseDragEvent(self, ev):
        # Ignore mouse drag events to disable dragging
        pass

I tried adding one view box for each segment and then clearing the other view boxes. Additionally, I experimented with using PlotWidget items and subplots. I also tried using mouse events instead of sigClicked.

why did you comment the main part of my problem ?
